# Input Random Value In Search Box In ROBOT FRAMEWORK

Tags: robotframework

I'm able to select a random value from a list but I'm not able to enter that value in the search box. The thing is **input text** requires two arguments i.e the locator & the value. I'm stuck with the value part now

```
*** Variables ***
@{cin}  U74999KA2016PTC096782  U22012CH1993PTC012939  U65999MH2016PTC287488

*** Test Cases ***
Search
  input text  ${SEARCH_BAR}
  ${value}  Evaluate  random.choice($cin)  random
  log to console  \nvalue: ${value}
  click element  ${SEARCH_BUTTON}
```

Comment: Hi, please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named [What to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What not to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read the [StackOverflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to generate a random value after you try to input blank text into the box

Change your code to

```
*** Variables ***
@{cin}  U74999KA2016PTC096782  U22012CH1993PTC012939  U65999MH2016PTC287488

*** Test Cases ***
Search
  ${value} =   Evaluate  random.choice($cin)  random
  input text  ${SEARCH_BAR}  ${value}

  log to console  \nvalue: ${value}
  click element  ${SEARCH_BUTTON}
```

Comment: I tried with the above code but I'm getting an error as - Message: invalid element state: Element must be user-editable in order to clear it.

Comment: Are you sure the ${SEARCH_BAR} is an input box and it can be cleared? make sure there is no element with the same id as ${SEARCH_BAR} value, and make sure its an Text Box that can be cleared

Comment: Yes. The code for Search bar is:  <input type="text" autocomplete="off" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-controls="react-autowhatever-1" class="react-autosuggest__input" placeholder="Search for a Person, Business or a Registration" value="">